# indices[3] = 36826 is not in [0, 36720)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, kaggle

Object detection code
%%time
model.train(dataset_train, dataset_val,
learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE,
epochs=4 if debug else 14,
layers='all',
augmentation=augmentation)

```
new_history = model.keras_model.history.history
for k in new_history: history[k] = history[k] + new_history[k]
```

Comment: The message seems obvious. 36826 is 127 more than allowed.

Comment: Try to format your code.